# Why is NPM autoprefixer not working on Windows - even after using "\"?

Tags: npm, terminal, postcss, autoprefixer

I'm trying to use the NPM Autoprefixer (as part of the Postcss extension). I get the following error every time I try to use NPM autp to run prefix:css in my terminal:

[image]

This the code of my package.json file:

```json
{
  "name": "natours",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "devserver": "live-server",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "concat:css": "concat -o css/style.concat.css css/icon-font.css css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b \"last 10 version\" css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css --output-style compressed",
    "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass concat:css prefix:css compress:css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.1"
  }
}
```

Following a few answers I've seen in other places, I tried adding \ before and after "last 10 versions" (I'm using Windows), as you can see in the code. But it didn't work at all, and I still get the exact same error as before.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly run your CLI as administrator then run
`npm cache clean --force`
This worked for me

Comment: Isn't this the code they already have, and what they describe doing to solve the problem?